# Visualization of raw RGB image data with 24bits using opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I would like to process a raw image using OpenCV. As far I know, it is not possible to open raw image using OpenCV.
I fllowed the [instaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682830/opencv-python-display-raw-image).

My raw picture is RGB with 24bits (the first 3 bytes represents the color values of red, green and blue in the same pixel).

My aim is to be able to process my picture using OpenCV functions.

How should I reshape my raw data?
I thought of (3, 1280, 1080) based on what i saw in the internet

How could I visualized the three pictures as "normal" picture? and how could I visualized he three pictures separably?

As small example I tried to *reshape* the bytes I read using:

```
a = np.arange(18).reshape(3,2,3, order='F')

a: [[[ 0  6 12]
     [ 3  9 15]]
    [[ 1  7 13]
     [ 4 10 16]]
    [[ 2  8 14]
     [ 5 11 17]]]
```

Comment: Give your picture data more accurate.

Comment: What is the exact size of your file in bytes? What is the height in pixels and width in pixels of your file?

Comment: @MarkSetchell the size is 1280 x 1080 x 3 (3 for RGB) -> 4147200 Bytes (no header)

Comment: What format are your images? Is it raw from a camera? If yes what type of camera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OpenCV** is able to read **NetPBM** ([Wikipedia entry for NetPBM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format)  format images, see `PPM Example` on linked page.

So you could just put a P6 (i.e. binary RGB) **NetPBM** header on the front of your image like this, then **OpenCV** can open it:

```
{ printf "P6\n1280 1080\n255\n" ; cat YourImage.raw ; } > result.ppm
```

---

If you are unfortunate enough to be on Windows, you can probably do it something like this:

```
echo "P6"          > header.txt
echo "1280 1080"  >> header.txt
echo "255"        >> header.txt
copy /b header.txt+YourImage.raw result.ppm
```

---

Alternatively, if you are on **Linux**, you probably have **ImageMagick**, and it is available for **macOS** and **Windows** too. So, at the command line in Terminal, you could convert your image to a `PNG` like tis:

```
convert -depth 8 -size 1280x1080 rgb:YourImage.raw result.png
```

You can then separate the individual channels and append them beside each other with

```
convert result.png -separate +append 3channels.png   # or use `-append` instead
```

Or, with auto-level contrast:

```
convert result.png -separate +append -auto-level 3channels.png
```